# Accessing custom attributes from model metadata in a tag helper

Tags: asp.net-core, data-annotations, tag-helpers, modelmetadata

I am working on a new project in .net Core having previously been working with .net Framework.

I wish to produce html select elements for boolean properties but using custom values instead of True and False (mainly "Yes" and "No").  In previous projects I have used the following method:

Create a custom attribute for boolean values:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class BooleanCustomValuesAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    public string TrueValue { get; set; }
    public string FalseValue { get; set; }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AdditionalValues["TrueValue"] = TrueValue;
        metadata.AdditionalValues["FalseValue"] = FalseValue;
    }
}
```

Use this in my model:

```
[BooleanCustomValues(TrueValue = "Yes", FalseValue = "No")]
public bool ThisWorks { get; set; }
```

Then in an editor template I can access these values for adding to a select:

```
object trueTitle;
ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.TryGetValue("TrueValue", out trueTitle);
trueTitle = trueTitle ?? "True";

object falseTitle;
ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.TryGetValue("FalseValue", out falseTitle);
falseTitle = falseTitle ?? "False";
```

I am now trying to do something similar in .net core, this time using a tag-helper instead of an editor template.

I understand that setting the AdditionalValues as above is not supported in core?

The closest I have found is this answer:
[Getting property attributes in TagHelpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40506865/getting-property-attributes-in-taghelpers#answer-46302342)

My tag helper code looks like this currenty (outputting p just for testing):

```
public class BooleanSelectTagHelper: TagHelper
    {
        [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
        public ModelExpression Source { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagName = "p";
            output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;

            var booleanAttribute = Source.Metadata.ContainerType.GetProperty(Source.Name).GetCustomAttribute(typeof(BooleanCustomValuesAttribute));

            var contents = $@"{booleanAttribute.TrueValue} or {booleanAttribute.FalseValue}";

            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(new HtmlString(contents));
        }
    }
```

However I can't get it to work as Source.Metadata.ContainerType.GetProperty(Source.Name).GetCustomAttributes() returns null.

Anoyingly when debugging and looking at Source.Metadata in a watch window I can see exactly what I want to access under Source.Metadata.Attributes - however this is not something that seems to be exposed outside the debugger.

Apologies for length of post - any pointers would be much appreciated (including tellimg me I am doing this all wrong!)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help, this is what I use to add the attributes for unobtrusive validation when I create custom `TagHelper`s. You can adapt this to whatever attribute you want to use.

From my experience, when you have the public member for `ModelExpression`, just call it `AspFor`, if you do not, it does not seem to get any of the attributes. But if the name matches, then I never have an issue. I'm currently using this on .NET 5.

```cs
    public class BooleanSelectTagHelper: TagHelper {
                
        public ModelExpression AspFor { get; set; }
        
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output){
            //... setup excluded for this example
            var attribute = this
                .AspFor
                .Metadata
                .ContainerType
                .GetProperty(AspFor.Name)
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequiredAttribute), false)                
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (attribute is RequiredAttribute requiredAttribute) {
                output.MergeAttribute("data-val", "true");
                output.MergeAttribute("data-val-required", requiredAttribute.FormatErrorMessage(AspFor.Name));                
            }
            //... code to display excluded for this example
        }
    }
```

I usually attempt to get the attribute, and then check whether it's of the desired type right inside of the `if` statement. Then access whatever you need to inside of the `if` branch.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `HtmlTargetElement` attribute on your tag helper:

```
[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "asp-for")] // <== Add this
public class BooleanSelectTagHelper: TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
    public ModelExpression Source { get; set; }
}
```

Also, don't forget to import your own tag helpers in `_ViewImports.cshtml` file after Microsoft's tag helpers. Replace the "WebApp" with the name of your assembly containing the tag helpers to add. Read more in [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0#addtaghelper-makes-tag-helpers-available).

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, WebApp
```